# snap builds OK but fails to run with error "gtk_clutter_init() failed Error: Can't open display: :1"

Tags: snapcraft

I am trying to build a snap package for Fotoxx.
I got a working build after days of effort, but it fails to execute.

When started, the app fails immediately with the error
"gtk_clutter_init() failed. Error: Can't open display: :1"

The same binary app (Fotoxx) runs OK if built with $ make install, so something must be missing or wrong in my snapcraft.yaml file.

Here is the snapcraft.yaml:

name: fotoxx
version: '23.76'
summary: Edit photos and manage a large collection
description: |
Navigate a large image collection with a thumbnail browser.
View and edit image files (RAW, jpeg, png, tiff ...).
Editing is done in 24 bits/color, output is 8 or 16 bits/color.
Fotoxx has extensive tools for edit, repair, and special effects.
View image updates as edit tools are applied interactively.
Undo and redo within and across edit functions.
File versioning: save and recall multiple edit stages.
Select image features or areas to edit separately from background.
Copy and paste area selections within and across images.
Combine functions: HDR, HDF, panorama, stack, images/text mashup.
Metadata edit and report: tags, captions, dates, locations ...
Search images using combination of metadata or folder/file names.
Albums: select images and arranged order with drag and drop.
Slide Show with animated transitions and pan/zoom.
Scalable world map with image markers - click marker for gallery.
Batch functions: convert, resize, upright, move, revise metatata.
User Guide (English) describes all functions in great detail.

grade: stable
confinement: strict
base: core20                  # Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

parts:
fotoxx:
plugin: make
source-type: tar
source: fotoxx-23.76-source.tar.gz
build-packages:
- g++
- make
- libgtk-3-dev
- liblcms2-dev
- libtiff-dev
- libpng-dev
- libjpeg-dev
- libclutter-1.0-dev
- libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev
- libchamplain-0.12-dev
- libchamplain-gtk-0.12-dev
stage-packages:
- xdg-utils
- x11-utils
- binutils
- dcraw
- libimage-exiftool-perl
- libatk-bridge2.0-0
- libatk1.0-0
- libatspi2.0-0
- libbrotli1
- libcairo-gobject2
- libcairo2
- libchamplain-0.12-0
- libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0
- libclutter-1.0-0
- libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
- libcogl-pango20
- libcogl-path20
- libcogl20
- libdatrie1
- libegl1
- libepoxy0
- libevdev2
- libfribidi0
- libgbm1
- libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
- libgraphite2-3
- libgtk-3-0
- libgudev-1.0-0
- libharfbuzz0b
- libicu66
- libinput10
- libjbig0
- libjson-glib-1.0-0
- libmtdev1
- libpango-1.0-0
- libpangocairo-1.0-0
- libpangoft2-1.0-0
- libpixman-1-0
- libpsl5
- libsoup2.4-1
- libthai0
- libtiff5
- libwacom2
- libwayland-client0
- libwayland-cursor0
- libwayland-egl1
- libwayland-server0
- libwebp6
- libxcb-render0
- libxcursor1
- libxdamage1
- libxkbcommon0
- libxml2

slots:
fotoxx:
interface: dbus
bus: session
name: fotoxx

apps:
fotoxx:
command: usr/bin/fotoxx
plugs:
- home                   # access user files in $HOME